# Repeated measures mixed model multinomial logistic regression

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, multinomial-logit

I have 1 continuous IV (cognitive ability) and 1 ordinal IV (task difficulty), that predict a categorical DV with 3 levels (type1, type2, type3), hence the multinomial logistic regression. Each subject did 3 tasks, hence the repeated measure.

Is there a way to do this in SPSS (preferable) are R? Could anyone point me to a similar example?

Comment: The r package [brms](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/brms.pdf) is the most user-friendly way I have found to do something like this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Bayesian statistics